# displaying a class to body using jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

when assigning a class bodyblue to body using jquery in second loop it fails.

below is my scenario

I have three **classes box** with randomly selected image and from **array items**,  there is a square **box002** at right lower portion, this **can be drag and droppped to any of three box** `if it find match the box will dissappear` . likwise three box will dissappear.

then a class **bodyblue is added to body** with backgroundImage named `middle bg` is added to body for `10 seconds` . after again 3 box appear for drag and drop.

in the **second level** after this three boxes are dragged&dropped and deleted, when **bodyblue is added to body the backgroundImage** **`middle bg`** **is not appearing in for 10 seconds.**

`How to add bodyblue backgroundImage to body using jquery in second level and third level?`

```js
var array2 = [];
var arraycart = [];
var disparray = [];
var bg = [];
var dataURL;
var timeOut;
counter = 0;

var items = [{
 label: '1',url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1'},
  {label: '2',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2'},
  {label: '3',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image3'},
  {label: '4',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image4'},
  {label: '5',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image5'},
  {label: '6',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image6'},
  {label: '7',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image7'},
  {label: '8',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image8'},
  {label: '9',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image9'},
  {label:'10',url:'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image10'}
];


var notes = ['https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image3',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image4',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image5',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image6',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image7',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image8',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image9',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image10'
];


var tempimages = [];
var notesselected = [];

array2 = items.slice();

var item;


//----------------------------------------------change backgroundImage----------------------------------------------------------


function changemainbackground() {
  debugger;
  var c = document.getElementById('main');


  var img = document.getElementById('main'),
    style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false),
    bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");

  // Display the url to the user
  //console.log('Image URL: ' + bi);


  bodycontents = document.getElementById('main');

  if (counter >= 0) {
    bodycontents.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bg[counter] + ')';
    d = bodycontents.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bg[counter] + ')';
    //console.log(d);    


  }
  counter++;

  //console.log("counter is"+counter);
  //console.log(bodycontents);
  //console.log(d);

}
//--------------------------^^^^^change backgroundImage end here^^^^^^^--------------------------------------------------------


//----------------------------------------------hiddenImage------------------------------------------------------------------------

hiddenimgnumber = 0;

var images = ['https://picsum.photos/200/300', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300'];

//var bg=['https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1','https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2'];
var bg = ['https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=2', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=3', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=4'];

var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
  image = document.getElementById('hiddenimageid');
  image.src = images[hiddenimgnumber];
}, 1)


function hiddenimage() {

  clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
  image = document.getElementById('hiddenimageid');
  image.src = images[hiddenimgnumber];

  //console.log(hiddenimgnumber);
  hiddenimgnumber++;


}

//-------------------------------------------------^^^hidden Image ends^^^------------------------------------------------------


window.onload = function() {}

function rvalue() {
  elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    //debugger;
    elements[i].style.border = "2px solid  #c57232 ";
    elements[i].style.borderBottom = "5px solid  #c57232 ";
    //object.style.borderRadius = "1-4 length|% / 1-4 length|%|initial|inherit"

  }

  ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
  boxtags = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
  //if array length is 0 then we need to identify the game as completed
  if (array2.length === 0) {
    alert('Game completed');
    return;

  }

  for (var index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length)

    item = array2[randomIndex];
    array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);

    try {
      //ptags[index].style.visibility = "visible";
      //ptags[index].textContent = "RS."+item.label;
      ptags[index].dataset.itemLabel = item.label;

      //using label as an identity
      tempimages.push({
        data: item,
        label: item.label
      });
      notesselected.push({
        data: item.url,
        label: item.label
      });

      boxtags[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + item.url + ')';

    } catch (err) {
      // console.log('Exception');
    }
  }

  var tlen = tempimages.length;
}


function displayAllImages() {
  try {

    if (tempimages.length == 0) {
      rvalue();

    }

    if (tempimages.length === 0) {
      image = document.getElementById('slide');
      image.style.display = 'none';
      return;
    }

    // getting random item from the available items
    var arr2 = tempimages;
    item = arr2[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr2.length)]

    image = document.getElementById('slide');
    //getting notes item
    //console.log(item);
    ///////console.log(item.label);
    var dataURL = notes.filter(a => a.indexOf("?text=" + item.label) > 0)[0];
    //var dataURL =item.url;
    //var dataURL = item.label;
    console.log(dataURL);
    image.src = dataURL;
    image.dataset.itemLabel = item.label;

  } catch (err) {
    //console.log(err.message);
  }
};

$(function() {
  displayAllImages();
});

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");


  var x = document.getElementById("slide").dataset.itemLabel;
  var y = ev.target.dataset.itemLabel;


  //add improvisation box drag is valid
  if (ev.target.tagName === "DIV") {
    y = ev.target.children[0].dataset.itemLabel;
  }

  //console.log(x);
  //console.log(y);

  if (x == y) {
    ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'initial';
    ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundImage = 'initial';
    ev.currentTarget.style.border = 'initial';
    var pParagraph = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;

    pParagraph.style.visibility = "hidden";

    item = this.item;
    tempimages = tempimages.filter(a => a.label !== item.label);



    if (tempimages.length == 0) {
      rvalue();
      hiddenimage();
      animateCongrat();

    }
    displayAllImages();
  } else {

  }
}


//----------------------------->>>animate congarat starts here-------------------------------------------------------------

var timeOut;

function animateCongrat() {


  //debugger;
  $('.congrats').show();

  clearTimeout(timeOut);
  addBlueBody();





  hideCongratAndBlueBody();
}



function addBlueBody() {

  $("html").css("background-color", "  #070755  ");
  $('body').addClass('bodyblue')

  //console.log(url);
  $('#container').hide();
  $('#2container').hide();
  $('#3container').hide();
  $('#2').hide();
  $('.completed').hide();

  
  

}

function hideCongratAndBlueBody() {
  timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
    $('.congrats').hide();
    $("html").css("background-color", "");
    $('body').removeClass('bodyblue')
    $('#container').show();
    $('#2container').show();
    $('#3container').show();
    $('#2').show();

    $('.completed').hide();
  

    changemainbackground();
  }, 10000);

}

//----------------------------->>>animate congarat ends here-------------------------------------------------------------
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dashed {
  border: 2px dashed #999 !important;
}

.bodyblue {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1000x600?text=Middle+bg);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

ul {
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
}

.box {
  width: calc(33.3% - 4px);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
  margin: -2px;
  background-color: #99ffff;
  height: 16vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box002 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40.3vh;
  left: 50.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.box002 img {
  width: 15.0vw;
  height: 15.0vh;
  border-radius: 0%;
}

#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: px solid #CC0000;
}

.containerr {
  border: px solid #FF3399;
}

.pic {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.container2 {
  width: 29.0vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 23.9vh;
  left: 19.2vw;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0);
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}

.reset img:hover {
  opacity: 1
}

.hiddenimage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4.3vh;
  left: 50vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hiddenimage img {
  width: 10.3vw;
  height: 10.5vh;
  border-radius: 15%;
}

.hand {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45.3vh;
  left: 17vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hand img {
  width: 25.3vw;
  height: 25.5vh;
  border-radius: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container2">
  <div class="containerr">
    <div class="pic" id="content">


      <div id="container">

        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10" style="">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12">
          <p name="values"></p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
  <img src="" draggable="true" id="slide" border="rounded" />
</div>

<div class="congrats">
  <div class="hiddenimage" style="display:none;">
    <img src="" id="hiddenimageid" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't really understand why all of this complicated code, when it sounds like what you're *really* asking is, how do I add a class to a element?  `$(selector).addClass()`

Comment: @erik-philips thanks for reply .  bodyblue class is added to body using the code which you have mentioned when three boxes get deleted using drag and drop..       .. My problem in next level when three boxes load after getting deleted, the bodblue class is not adde to body.... ie the jquery is not working

Comment: @erik-philips is there a way i can get the bodyblue class to appear for 10 seconds in second loop

Comment: The whole for loop  of rvalue() function is taken in time interval

Comment: @lds thanks for reply.. how to correct it, can you give little more innformation please..

Comment: Delay is success .But the event ondrop is not firing .Bellow solution for delay by change rvalue() function and displayAllImages() function

Comment: Your programe is running well now

Comment: @lds please wait im correcting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184383/discussion-between-geek-and-lds).

Answer (score -2):

```js
<script>
        var array2 = [];
        var arraycart = [];
        var disparray = [];
        var bg = [];
        var dataURL;
        var timeOut;
        counter = 0;

        var items = [{
            label: '1', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1'
        },
        { label: '2', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2' },
        { label: '3', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image3' },
        { label: '4', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image4' },
        { label: '5', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image5' },
        { label: '6', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image6' },
        { label: '7', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image7' },
        { label: '8', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image8' },
        { label: '9', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image9' },
        { label: '10', url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image10' }
        ];


        var notes = ['https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1',
            'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2',
            'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image3',
            'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image4',
            'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image5',
            'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image6',
            'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image7',
            'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image8',
            'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image9',
            'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image10'
        ];


        var tempimages = [];
        var notesselected = [];

        array2 = items.slice();

        var item;


        //----------------------------------------------change backgroundImage----------------------------------------------------------

       
        function changemainbackground() {
            debugger;
            var c = document.getElementById('main');


            var img = document.getElementById('main'),
                style = img.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(img, false),
                bi = style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");

            // Display the url to the user
            //console.log('Image URL: ' + bi);


            bodycontents = document.getElementById('main');

            if (counter >= 0) {
                bodycontents.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bg[counter] + ')';
                d = bodycontents.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bg[counter] + ')';
                //console.log(d);    


            }
            counter++;

            //console.log("counter is"+counter);
            //console.log(bodycontents);
            //console.log(d);

        }
        //--------------------------^^^^^change backgroundImage end here^^^^^^^--------------------------------------------------------


        //----------------------------------------------hiddenImage------------------------------------------------------------------------

        hiddenimgnumber = 0;

        var images = ['https://picsum.photos/200/300', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300'];

        //var bg=['https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1','https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2'];
        var bg = ['https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=2', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=3', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=4'];

        var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function () {
            image = document.getElementById('hiddenimageid');
            image.src = images[hiddenimgnumber];
        }, 1)


        function hiddenimage() {

            clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
            image = document.getElementById('hiddenimageid');
            image.src = images[hiddenimgnumber];

            //console.log(hiddenimgnumber);
            hiddenimgnumber++;


        }

        //-------------------------------------------------^^^hidden Image ends^^^------------------------------------------------------


        window.onload = function () { }

        function rvalue() {
            elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
            
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                //debugger;
                elements[i].style.border = "2px solid  #c57232 ";
                elements[i].style.borderBottom = "5px solid  #c57232 ";
                //object.style.borderRadius = "1-4 length|% / 1-4 length|%|initial|inherit"
               
            }

            ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
            boxtags = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
            //if array length is 0 then we need to identify the game as completed
            if (array2.length === 0) {
                alert('Game completed');
                return;

            }
            for (var index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
                randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length)

                item = array2[randomIndex];
                array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);
                tempimages.push({
                    data: item,
                    label: item.label
                });
                notesselected.push({
                    data: item.url,
                    label: item.label
                });
            }
            var timeOuts = setTimeout(() => {
                for (var index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
                  //  randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length)

                    //item = array2[randomIndex];
                    //array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);
                    item = array2[index];
                    try {

                        ptags[index].dataset.itemLabel = item.label;


                        //tempimages.push({
                        //    data: item,
                        //    label: item.label
                        //});
                        //notesselected.push({
                        //    data: item.url,
                        //    label: item.label
                        //});

                        boxtags[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + item.url + ')';

                    } catch (err) {
                        // console.log('Exception');
                    }
                }
            }, 5000);
            var tlen = tempimages.length;
        }


        function displayAllImages() {
            try {
                var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length)
                if (tempimages.length == 0) {
                  
                    var fitem = array2[randomIndex];
                   
                    tempimages.push({
                        data: fitem,
                        label: fitem.label
                    });
                    rvalue();
                }

                if (tempimages.length === 0) {
                    image = document.getElementById('slide');
                    image.style.display = 'none';
                    return;
                }

                // getting random item from the available items
                var arr2 = tempimages;
              //  item = arr2[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr2.length)]
                
                item = arr2[0];
                image = document.getElementById('slide');
               
                //getting notes item
                //console.log(item);
                ///////console.log(item.label);
               
                var dataURL = notes.filter(a => a.indexOf("?text=" + item.label) > 0)[0];
                //var dataURL =item.url;
                //var dataURL = item.label;
              
                console.log(dataURL);
                image.src = dataURL;
                image.dataset.itemLabel = item.label;
               
            } catch (err) {
                //console.log(err.message);
               
            }
        };

        $(function () {
           
            displayAllImages();
        });

        function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
        }

        function drop(ev) {
           
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

           
            var x = document.getElementById("slide").dataset.itemLabel;
          

            var y = ev.target.dataset.itemLabel;

           
            //add improvisation box drag is valid
            if (ev.target.tagName === "DIV") {
                var eid = ev.target.id;
                var ind = parseInt(eid) - 10;
                var imgdata = tempimages[ind];
                $.each(imgdata, function (key, value) {
                    if (key == 'label')
                        y = value;
                    //alert(key + ": " + value);
                });
               // alert(imgdata[1]);
                //y = ev.target.children[0].dataset.itemLabel;
                //alert(y);
            }

            //console.log(x);
            //console.log(y);
          
            if (x == y) {
                ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'initial';
                ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundImage = 'initial';
                ev.currentTarget.style.border = 'initial';
                var pParagraph = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;

                pParagraph.style.visibility = "hidden";

                item = this.item;
                tempimages = tempimages.filter(a => a.label !== item.label);


                
                if (tempimages.length == 0) {
                    rvalue();
                    hiddenimage();
                    animateCongrat();

                }
                displayAllImages();
            } else {

            }
        }


        //----------------------------->>>animate congarat starts here-------------------------------------------------------------

        var timeOut;

        function animateCongrat() {

           
            //debugger;
            $('.congrats').show();

            clearTimeout(timeOut);
            addBlueBody();


            hideCongratAndBlueBody();
        }



        function addBlueBody() {

            $("html").css("background-color", "  #070755  ");
            $('body').addClass('bodyblue')

            //console.log(url);
            $('#container').hide();
            $('#2container').hide();
            $('#3container').hide();
            $('#2').hide();
            $('.completed').hide();




        }

        function hideCongratAndBlueBody() {
            timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
               
                $('.congrats').hide();
                $("html").css("background-color", "");
                $('body').removeClass('bodyblue')
                $('#container').show();
                $('#2container').show();
                $('#3container').show();
                $('#2').show();

                $('.completed').hide();


                changemainbackground();
            }, 10000);

        }

    </script>
```